# Please explain Action in Struts 2.0 XML file

Tags: struts2, struts-action

```
<action name="userLogin" class="com.cc.ad.web.common.UserLoginAction">
    <result name="error">/user-login.jsp</result>
    <result name="redirect" type="redirect">${retUrl}</result>
    <result name="customerRedirect" type="redirect">${customerRedirect}</result>
    <result name="supplierRedirect" type="redirect">${supplierRedirect}</result>
    <result name="diamondViewRedirect" type="redirect">${diamondViewRedirect}</result>          
    <result name="supplierPopupRedirect" type="redirect">${supplierPopup}</result>
    <result name="customerPopupRedirect" type="redirect">${customerPopup}</result>  
</action>
```

Above I show one of many things written in my Struts XML file. Here nothing is define in the method attributes so I am confused about which method of UserLoginAction class is called when this action is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If method name is not specified in the action configuration, Struts will look for a method named `execute` by default.

[Struts 2.0 Action Configuration Doc](http://struts.apache.org/docs/action-configuration.html)